# Using an array as a default parameter in a PHP function

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to use an array as a default parameter in a PHP function?

I would like to do the following:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);

function sample($var1, $var2, $var3 = $arr){
    echo $var1.$var2;
    print_r($var3);
}

sample('a','b');
// Should still work without the third parameter and default to $arr
```

Comment: No, `$var3 = array(1,2,3,4)` would work though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, this is not possible, the right hand expression of the default value must be a constant or array literal, i.e.

```
function sample($var1, $var2, $var3 = array(1, 2, 3, 4))
{
}
```

If you want this behaviour, you could use a closure:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

$sample = function ($var1, $var2, array $var3 = null) use ($arr) {
    if (is_null($var3)) {
        $var3 = $arr;
    }

    // your code
}

$sample('a', 'b');
```

You could also express it with a class:

```
class Foo
{
    private static $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

    public static function bar($var1, $var2, array $var3 = null)
    {
        if (is_null($var3)) {
            $var3 = self::$arr;
        }

        // your code here
    }
}

Foo::bar('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Is the `array` in `test($var1, $var2, array $var3 = null)` valid notation? Never seen that before!

Comment: I come from a JavaScript background so PHP classes are a little strange to me, so I definitely prefer the closure!

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa It's valid, the passed value must either be an array or the default value `null`.

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa The class example is like `Sample = { arr: [1,2,3,4], test: function(v1, v2, v3) { v3 = v3 || this.arr }}`

Comment: if you're using `array $var3 = null` and checking  `is_null( $var3 )` would there be any difference in checking `! is_array( $var3 )`?

Comment: @JaeGeeTee The argument is either an array or null, so that should answer your question :)

Answer (score 7):

You can't pass `$arr` into the function definition, you'll have to do:

```
function sample($var1, $var2, $var3 = array('test')){
    echo $var1.$var2;
    echo print_r($var3);
}

sample('a','b'); // output: abArray ( [0] => test ) 1
```

or, if you want to be really dirty (I wouldn't recommend it..):

```
$arr = array('test');

function sample($var1, $var2, $var3 = null){
    if($var3 == null){
      global $arr;
      $var3 = $arr;
    }
    echo $var1.$var2;
    echo print_r($var3);
}

sample('a','b');
```

Answer (score 5):

(It might not be a complete answer, but it covers some useful cases.)

If you want to get one or more options using an array as an argument in a function (or a method), setting a default set of options might not help. Instead, you can use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/array-replace).

For example, let's consider a sample `$options` argument which gets an array with two keys, `count` and `title`. Setting a default value for that argument leads overriding it when using the function with any custom `$option` value passed. In the example, if we set `$options` to have only one `count` key, then the `title` key will be removed. One of the right solutions is the following:

```php
function someCoolFunc($options = []) {
    $options = array_replace([
        "count" => 144,
        "title" => "test"
    ], $options);
    
    // ... 
}
```

In the example above, you will be ensured that `count` and `title` indexes are present, even if the user supplies an empty array (keep in mind, the order of the arguments in `array_replace()` function is important).

**Note:** In the explained case, using a class (or interface) is also an option, but one reason to choose arrays over it might be simplicity (or even performance).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the last example above.  Here was my comparable test:

```
function someFunc($options = [])
    {
        $options = array_replace([
            "<br>", "<b>", "<i>", "<u>", "<hr>", "<span>"
        ], $options);
        print_r($options);
    }
```

here is the result:

```
>>> somefunc()
Array
(
    [0] => <br>
    [1] => <b>
    [2] => <i>
    [3] => <u>
    [4] => <hr>
    [5] => <span>
)
=> null
```

Yet looks what happens when you try to add a tag.  Notice what happens to the original values.  Element [0] is changed.  The array is not added to:

```
>>> someFunc(["<div>"])
Array
(
    [0] => <div>
    [1] => <b>
    [2] => <i>
    [3] => <u>
    [4] => <hr>
    [5] => <span>
)
=> null
```

This would allow you to add an element to default option:

```
function someFunc($options = array())
    {
       array_push($options, "<br>", "<b>", "<i>", "<u>", "<hr>", "<span>");
       return $options;
    }
```

Here is what results:

```
>>> someFunc()
=> [
     "<br>",
     "<b>",
     "<i>",
     "<u>",
     "<hr>",
     "<span>",
   ]

---
 someFunc(["<div>","<table>"]);
=> [
     "<div>",
     "<table>",
     "<br>",
     "<b>",
     "<i>",
     "<u>",
     "<hr>",
     "<span>",
   ]
```

this way, the default values get added to.